# Scheme n-ary functions

Tags: function, scheme

I'm looking to make my own custom < function that can take any number of arguments in scheme. How would I go about doing this?

I'm thinking I have to do something like (and (b< x y) (b< y z)) but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well... what does it **mean** if (b< x y z) returns #t? And why is that a useful result?

Comment: @Karl: In standard Scheme, `<` returns `#t` if its argument list is in sorted order; I imagine `b<` would do the same.  It's handy for writing *e.g.* `(< min-bound x max-bound)` instead of `(and (< min-bound x) (< x max-bound))`.

Comment: Scheme's `<` function _already_ takes any number of arguments, including 0. Why would you need a custom `<` function?

Comment: well for a class project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an implementation of `<` that works like the one in Scheme, using `b<` as the binary less-than operation:

```
(define (< . args)
  (cond 
    [(null? args) #t]
    [(null? (cdr args)) #t]
    [(b< (car args) (car (cdr args)))
     (apply < (cdr args))]))
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up doing a similar version except having an or statement for checking the list/cdr of the list

Answer (score 2):

well, to start off, you define a variadic function with something like

```
(define (my-< . numbers)
    <body>
)
```

then numbers will be a list which contains the arguments. From there you'll need some sort of loop or recursion so that it works for an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: Like to add `case-lambda` to this. (http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-6.html)

Comment: I have that part of the function.